# How can I browse old mails in an IMAP folder?

Tags: email, imap

Both the build-in mail client (Android 2.1) and K-9 mail, display the most recent `n` messages received during the last `m` days, where `m` and `n` are configuration items. Messages older than `m` days are invisible.

It's certainly sensible to hide old mail my by default, but how cannot I lookup an old message in INBOX or another folder? Even if the INBOX folder is huge, retrieving all headers should be an option.

Answer (score 0):

In K-9 Mail, if you scroll down in your inbox, it shows the option "Load up to `n` more", and by repeating this you can go back further and further.

Comment: No. This only loads some subsets of the mails (I suspect recent)

Comment: Weird, on my phone it goes 100 mails back chronologically with each load (I've set my mailbox to show 100 latest).

Answer (score 0):

When using both features i.e. n messages in the last m days I have always found it to be buggy.

If you want to pick up loads of old messages would suggest going into the account settings for that account, removing the m days option and changing the fetching option from xKB to just headings. Would also suggest changing n messages to a higher value, one that is likely to pick up however many you want. Then refresh your account - you should get exactly what you need now.

Comment: I have set “[Sync messages from](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/wiki/Manual-accountsettings#sync-messages-from)” to “any time (no limit)” (which is the /m/ in your answer) but still don’t get the one old message I can access via `pine` (a desktop IMAP client) to show up in K-9 Mail 5.006 (using the very same IMAP settings)…